# Can't understand the problem with the code

Tags: reentrant-attacks

I am reading the following tutorial.

[Tutorial](https://ftsrg.mit.bme.hu/blockchain-ethereumlab/guide.html)

What is the problem with the following code:

```
function withdraw(uint amount) public {
     require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount);
     balances[msg.sender] -=amount;
     payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
     transactions++;

}
```

How is this code causing reentrancy attack?

Comment: What do you mean what, is wrong with this code? Do you get any error? 
Please ask your question more clear.

Comment: @Amin, How is this code causing reentrancy attack?

Comment: There is nothing in the page about reentrancy attacks. What makes you think that code is vulnerable?

Comment: nothing wrong with this function